# add arrayList into HashMap with looping [kotlin code]

Tags: kotlin, while-loop, hashmap, iterator

I'm trying to put the **itemList** as array which is fetching from other function, and put it into Hash Map. After the loop finished, I try to print the content which is wrong.

```
class ExpandableItemClass : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var expandableListAdapter: ExpandableListViewAdapter? = null
    private lateinit var titleList : List<String>   
    private lateinit var myHasMap: HashMap<String, List<String>>  
    private var itemList : ArrayList<String> ? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pobitrota)

        titleList = ArrayList()
        myHasMap = HashMap()
        itemList = ArrayList()


        getAllTitles()

        expandableListAdapter = ExpandableListViewAdapter(this@PobitrotaActivity, titleList, myHasMap)
        pobitrota_recyclerListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter)


    }



    private fun getAllTitles() {
        var pRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Titles")
        pRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).clear()
                    for (item in snapshot.children){
                        var subItem = item.getValue(Title::class.java)
                        if(subItem!!.getMainTitleId().equals("-M_FyZJbyXf3fLFyEuiT")){
                            (titleList as ArrayList<String>).add(subItem.getTitleName())

                            getAllItems(item.key!!)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        })
    }


    private fun getAllItems(titleId: String) {
        var pRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("DropdownItems")
        pRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    dropdownList!!.clear()
                    for (item in snapshot.children){
                        var stdItem = item.getValue(Item::class.java)
                        if(stdItem!!.getTitleId().equals(titleId)){
                            itemList!!.add(stdItem.getItemName())
                        }
                    }

                    while(index < titleList.size){
                        myHasMap.put(titleList[index], itemList!!)

                        break
                    }
                    index = index + 1


                    for(key in myHasMap.keys){
                        Log.d("TAG", key+" => "+myHasMap[key])
                    }

                    expandableListAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }

        })
    }


}
```

Here is the result like below:

```
//1st iterator:
title1 => [item1, item2, item3]

//2nd iterator:
title1 => [item4, item5]
title2 => [item4, item5]


//3rd iterator:
title1 => [item6, item7]
title2 => [item6, item7]
title3 => [item6, item7]
```

Here is the result and it is correct. I hope so:

```
//1st iterator:
title1 => [item1, item2, item3]

//2nd iterator:
title1 => [item1, item2, item3]
title2 => [item4, item5]


//3rd iterator:
title1 => [item1, item2, item3]
title2 => [item4, item5]
title3 => [item6, item7]
```

I am guessing my problem is that hasmap can't save the data added to the hasmap.

**What is the correct way to add data into hashmap? How can I get the right results?**

Comment: What is the `titleList` variable? Where does it come from? How is it related to `itemList`?

Comment: This is hard to answer because your provided code cannot generate this output. Please give a minimal and reproducible example. My first guess is, that you mutate `itemList` after it is added to the `HashMap`. This will also change the `itemList` that you put into the `HashMap`.

Comment: Adam Millerchip i have updated my question.

Comment: Du you mutate `itemList` between iterations or reassign it?

Comment: No. after add hashmap data i have just call adapter

Comment: Then we need more information. The `while` loop that is used as a `if` looks a bit strange but should work. A complete example that can reproduce your issue would be great.

Comment: How do you know which items in `itemsList` should correspond to the titles in `titleList`? `itemsList` is one single list, but you want to separate the items by title?

Comment: Again , updated my post. which will help you to understand my issue . thanks all

Comment: Sorry I'm not an Android dev and your code is very difficult to follow. I think your question is not really "add arrayList into HashMap with looping" but is really something like "How to get data from Firestore and store it in a Map?" - but not knowing about Android or Firestore I can't help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example how you can add an arrayList in other array of bundle

```
 val items = eventData.get(EVENT_PARAM_CART_ITEM) as ArrayList<Item>
 var arrayOf = arrayListOf<Bundle>()

 for ((index, item) in items.withIndex()) {
           
            val itemJeggings = Bundle().apply {
                putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, items[index].itemId.toString())
                putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_BRAND, items[index].brand)
                putLong(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.QUANTITY, items[index].quantity?.toLong()!!)
                putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CURRENCY, items[index].currency)
                putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE, items[index].price?.toDouble()!!)
            }
            arrayOf.add(itemJeggings)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Follow This  i dont have enough time to solve the Whole thing i guess u will understand from this

```
fun main() {
    // initialize the hashmap
    val hash = hashMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>()
    // put the keys with empty lists into the hashmap
    hash.put("bro", mutableListOf())
    hash.put("sis", mutableListOf())
    // add items to the value (the list) of existing keys
    hash.get("bro")?.add("rahat")
    hash.get("sis")?.add("mia")
    hash.get("bro")?.add("tech")
    hash.get("sis")?.add("user")
    // print size and content
    println("Hash size is ${hash.size.toString()}")
    println(hash)
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Hash size is 2
{sis=[mia, user], bro=[rahat, tech]}
```

Comment: bro, 
I did not get my expected output. Is there another way can you help me?